# Virtual box based development for Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, virtualbox, embedded-linux

I am new to embedded linux development.I have inherited a particular way of Embedded linux development from the previous developer.
I was just wondering if there is a more industry standard way of working.
This is how he was working,
There is an ARM embedded linux board which is not on the corporate network and has a fixed IP address of 192.168.0.52.I have a virtualbox based linux host which is connected directly to this linux board via an Ethernet cable.This host has an NFS shared with the target for running the cross compiled binaries.I have to set a fixed IP address for the host of 192.168.0.50.Then I can telnet with the target to run the compiled binaries on the NFS folder. Also as the VM host is not connected to the corporate network.I cannot use the company issued SVN for version control.So what I do is have a shared folder via virtual box between Windows and Linux host and I manually keep transferring the files which I have to commit/test.
What I would I ideally like, is both networks connected to the corporate network,so that I can update the OS,use version control.Is there way by which the VM on Windows access the corporate network and also be connected to the target.IT is not willing to give a static IP to the target.If we connect the target via DHCP what is the best way to discover it on the network.Also IT is concerned about the traffic it  will generate.Can I use a switch to create a subnetwork,so that the target can have a fixed address?
Another question is they are open to a linux based host as well.Is a VM based linux any worse off than a Linux PC.The only problem I have been having are networking based issues,not really Virtualbox issues.But I am curious to know if there are any limitations at all.

Comment: You can add second network adapter to VM.

Comment: Yes, Alex is right.  And while it can be good to keep your static IP embedded devices off the corporate network, OTOH, at some point they need to see at least a simulation of real traffic (because *interesting things* can happen when they do) and if you don't have a traffic simulator, plugging them into the building is better than nothing.  Also beware tripping over the ARP cache if you unplug one board and rapidly plug in another with the same IP address (but a different MAC address).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the VM connected to the corporate network, you can setup the VM network adapter in bridge mode.
In order to discover the embedded device, you can use the arp command (for instance: **arm -i eth0 -a**).
If you have got two network interfaces you could also connect the remote device directly through this interface and setup a dhcp server in your VM.

Personally, I think that with the VM you can do everything that you need (cross-compiling the Kernel and bootloader and creating the remote File System). I have been using a VM for embedded linux development on a AT91SAM board without problems at all.